# Manual CSRF Verification

Tags: python, django, csrf

I have a e-commerce Django application that automatically verifies all incoming `POST` requests with CSRF token using the `CSRFViewMiddleware`.

Now, for payments, I'm using a payment gateway where I pass the relevant details along with the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` so that it is returned back to me when the transaction on 3rd party site is complete. So, when the user is re-directed back to my site, I get a

```
403 Forbidden
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

How do I fix this? Is there any way I can manually check `csrftoken` using `request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken')` or something like that.

I would prefer not to bypass csrf totally as I want it to be secure (atleast, as much as possible).

**Edit** I understand `csrfmiddleware` token needs to be passed in the header but I cannot do that as there are only limited things I can do with a 3rd party payment gateway.

Comment: You should not be passing the CSRF token to third party sites.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid fair enough. The thing is I have a couple of payment options where I process some options and the others are processed by a 3rd party site. How do I secure this process then?)

Comment: Unlike a human user, any half-decent external service cannot be tricked into sending a request to your site with information from a different site (the attacker). Most of them don't depend on cookies or sessions either, so CSRF attacks are inherently useless. You secure the request by whichever authentication mechanism the third-party service provides.

Comment: Ok, in that case, how do I disable `csrf` validation. I used `@csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` but that did not help, i.e., still get a 403 Forbidden Error relating to csrf.

Comment: See [decorating class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views). Decorating `post()` won't work in this case, you need to decorate `dispatch()` or the result of `as_view()`.

Answer (score 2):

From this snippet, I get a feeling that you may not quite understand what is CSRF:

> I have a e-commerce Django application that automatically verifies **all
>   incoming POST requests** with CSRF token using the CSRFViewMiddleware.

That's part your problem right there. CSRF is only for those requests that are made from your site, to your site (see [OWASP's definition of CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)):

> Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is a type of attack that occurs when
>   a malicious Web site, email, blog, instant message, or program causes
>   **a user’s Web browser to perform an unwanted action on a trusted site
>   for which the user is currently authenticated.**

You need CSRF tokens only on those forms that are generated by your site, and post to your site. In addition, any javascript code that sends a POST request should also be properly protected.

For all other end points - for example, if some payment provider is posting the result back to your application - you do not want to enable CSRF protection otherwise the requests will continue to fail.

Comment: Yes. That clears my thought process. So I tried using @csrf_exempt over my post view that accepts post requests but I still get a 403 Csrf error. Any idea why?

Comment: `csrf_exempt` should prevent CSRF errors. If you are still getting errors, make sure that the exempt view is actually being called, and post the view.